# Applying Ferrari's method to a quartic

Tags: polynomials, quartics

I was interested in early solutions to quartics and cubics, so I read about Ferrari's method for solving the quartic. The book I read gives no specific example, but I was working through the equation

$$x^{4}+6x^{3}=6x^{2}+30x+11$$

or

$$x^{4}+6x^{3}-6x^{2}-30x-11=0$$

According to his method, the first thing we need to do is get rid of the $x^{3}$ by substituting, is this the correct substitution? Where do I go after this?$$x=v-\frac{6}{4}$$

So,

$$(v-\frac{6}{4})^{4}+6(v-\frac{6}{4})^{3}-6(v-\frac{6}{4})^{2}-30(v-\frac{6}{4})-11=0$$

Answer (score 1):

> ...is this the correct substitution?

Yes

> Where do I go after this?

Substitute:
\begin{align*}
  x^4 + 6x^3 - 6x^2 - 30x - 11 &= 0\\
  \left(v - \frac64\right)^4 + 6\left(v - \frac64\right)^3 - 6\left(v - \frac64\right)^2 - 30\left(v - \frac64\right) - 11 &= 0\\
  &\vdots
\end{align*}

Comment: How is the $x^{3}$ eliminated? If anything, this looks more complicated than it was.

Comment: @Citut, when you expand the $(v - \frac64)^4 + \cdots - 11$ expression, you get an expression with no cubic term.  It may look more complicated, but it is what the method calls for.  Solving quartic equations in general is rarely a simple process.

Comment: @tipler I guess I should have expected that. I'll see what I can do, thanks.